# geom_histogram with frequency data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a histogram plot with ggplot starting from a frequency table.
The freuqency table is the following:

| Income | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 0-10 | 60 |
| 10-30 | 50 |
| 30-60 | 40 |
| 60-100 | 10 |

I create:

- a data.frame of the data `es1_=data.frame(income=c(0,10,30,60,100),VALUE=c(0,60,50,40,10),DENSITY=c(0,60/10,50/20,40/30,10/40))`
- the break vector `intervalli=c(0,10,30,60,100)`
- a histogram `es1_ %>%  ggplot()+ geom_histogram(aes(x=INCOME,weight=DENSITY),breaks=intervalli)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPhFR.jpg)

Is it possible obtain the same histogram without edit manualy the DENSITY data?
How can obtain the same plot with the geom_histogram standard option?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have unequal bins, a better chart type would probably just be a bar chart. With your data in the current format it's a bit messy to get rid of the extra row, but you can do `with(es1_, data.frame(group = paste0(income[-length(income)],"-",income[-1]),value = VALUE[-1])) |>ggplot() + aes(group, value/sum(value)) + geom_col()`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. With this approach I obtain a different plot and I lost the density property of the histogram's bins.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your method is for calculating the density, but you could implement it mathematically instead of writing the values manually: `data.frame(INCOME=c(0,10,30,60,100),VALUE=c(0,60,50,40,10)) %>% 
  mutate(DENSITY = replace_na(VALUE / ((row_number() - 1) * 10), 0))`

Comment: I can't figure out your definition of density. either. Normally you scale the density to the area under all the bars is 1. Here if you did length*width for each of the bars and added them together you would get 160

Comment: I am unable to find any pattern to calculate density. Can you provide more information?